# How to replace one view with other views at the push of a single button inside a single ViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiimageview

I have an application that I am working where I have a UITableView on one particular screen.  Over top of this UITableView (which is already preloaded with data), is a UIImageView giving the user instructions on how to fill out the table (the table underneath has textfields for the user to enter data).  On this UIImageView, is a button that the user will press to begin entering data.

Once the user does this, I want the UIImageView on display to be removed, revealing the UITableView underneath, and also display a UIImageView at the bottom of the screen that contains multiple buttons which form a unique keypad that the user will use to enter data.

Now, I am able to remove the UIImageView with the instructions when the user presses the button.  My problem is, how do I then present to the user a UIImageView that will appear below the UITableView?  I initially added the UIImageView that is the keypad, and created for it, and all of the buttons that are on top of it, corresponding IBOutlet property references, which is why I don't have any code in my .m file where I programmatically added the subViews to the main view.

However, the UIImageView is on display from the beginning at screen launch. The functionality I am trying to mimic is the same as the one where a user enables a UITextField, and a keypad automatically appears from underneath.  This is what I am trying to accomplish.

Here is the method that get's called when the user presses the button to remove the instructional UIImageView, and supposed to add the keypad UIImageView (which was added to the screen initially via IB in storyboard):

```
- (void)buttonPressed {

    [_instructionCount removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:_keypadView];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UIView as the 'base view' of your application.  At the bottom of that UIView place your keypad view; above that, also in your base UIView, place your UITableView.  A table view does not need to be on the full display (although it frequently is).

Once you have your base view, use a modal controller to present your 'instructions' view.  A modal controller will have a dismiss button.  You shouldn't have to deal with the lower level of adding and removing subviews based on button clicks.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  I unfortunately need the UITableView to be underneath the instructional UIImageView because the table has textfields that the user sees (and is not completely covered by the UIImageView), and the UIImageView is designed such that it is actually pointing to the visible textfields.  This is why I am using the approach that I described above :-)